# What is the Festival Plaza and how does it work?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I get that it's basically the online hub of Pokemon Sun and Moon, but what exactly can I do here and how does it all work?

I randomly talk to people and they give me coins to spend - should I be saving this currency for one big purchase later or is everything pretty cheap?

What are all the possible unlockable buildings? I don't want to put a specific building somewhere and regret my choice because I got rid of one that I should have kept.

How do all of the buildings work? Do I just leave my Pokemon at these buildings and come back later? Is it based on time or steps or something in game?

Comment: Useful reference: http://www.serebii.net/sunmoon/festivalplaza.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its where players up for Battles & Trades, but there is far more to it than just that as there are many stores and things to do within the whole area.
As you do more things in the Festival Plaza, then more facilities and more things to do in those facilities will become available as you level up. This makes it very like to the Join Avenue in Black 2 & White 2. To level up, you need to earn Festival Coins by doing a variety of activities.